# Uncaught TypeError: FormData constructor: Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLFormElement. in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, form-data

My form is like this demo

[image: resume]

Q.1 I would like to convert this form to ajax but it seems like my ajax code lacks something. On submit doesn't do anything at all.

Q2. I also want the function to fire on change when the file has been selected not to wait for a submit.

Q3. I want to when I clicked on Next step button. The all of form save And go to next page.

My blade

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('update', auth()->id()) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('put')
    <fieldset>
        @include('Home.steps.step-1')
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        @include('Home.steps.step-2')
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        @include('Home.steps.step-3')
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        @include('Home.steps.step-4')
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        @include('Home.steps.step-5')
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        @include('Home.steps.step-6')
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.btn-next').on('click',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr("{{ route('update', auth()->id()) }}"),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

I get this error in console.

[image: error]

> Uncaught TypeError: FormData constructor: Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give form element not button

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form-id'));
```

Comment: I see this error again . https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcntJ.png My problem did not solve yet/

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi try `var formData = new FormData($('#form-id')[0]);`

Comment: This happened because you created your `FormData` with the `this` keyword. The `this` keyword is used to refer to the element that triggered the javascript function. 

In your case, it was a button click, so `this` will reference the button. 
 If you had triggered your function with form submit, you wouldn't have encountered this error.

So when you create the new FormData, you now have to pass it the id of your form element, not 'this'